# jquery 1.7.2 print plug in

Tags: jquery

how can I make a link to print a page, just using the browser basic print dialogue and that also work in older browser, including IE7?

Also is there any jquery 172 plug in available?  My knowledge of jquery is basic and of javascript even less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call `window.print();` on click.

```
<a id="print" href="#" onclick="window.print(); return false">print this page</a>
```

or not use the onclick attribute and add a listener like

```
document.getElementById('print').onclick = function () {
    window.print(); 
    return false;
}
```

or with jQuery

```
$('#print').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  window.print(); 
});
```